Unity - layer mask parameter in ray cast reduce over head?
Sorry for my pool english.
It's a simple question, Does layer mask parameter in unity ray cast ignoring non-target layer array and reducing calculate over head?
It's not a problem or issue but i want to know about this.
I can't found it on google..

Yes, Unity skips over all layers not withing the layerMask. As result Unity has to do less calculations.
